# Отмена вызова активити у AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager

Всем привет, в Андроид приложении использую `AlarmManager` для установки расписания срабатывания уведомления через `NotificationManager`.

Но беда в том, что как только приходит уведомление сразу срабатывает `pending intent` и вызывается активити. Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы просто присылалось уведомление по заданному расписанию?

Как я поняла это из-за того, что я устанавливаю один из 4 флагов `AlarmManager`. Есть ли способ как-то это обойти?

```
Intent intentNotif = new Intent(context,StartActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intentNotif,0);
notification = createNotification(
                "Text1",
                "Text2",context,pIntent);
am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+5000,10000,pIntent);
        manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);

Вот сам метод для создания уведомления
public static Notification createNotification(String content, String title, Context context, PendingIntent pIntent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_goal_image);
        builder.setTicker("Be better");
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setContentText(content);

        return builder.build();
    }
```

Comment: Код покажите..  Что вы в интент кладете.

Comment: Это из-за того, что Вы передаёте в `AlarmManager` pending intent на запуск Activity. Вместо этого нужно передать `PendingIntent` на запуск Broadcast Receiver и уже в нём выводить уведомление

Comment: @pavel  код добавила выше

Comment: @woess код добавила выше, а нельзя не использовать Broadcast Receiver а вместо него Сервис?

Comment: Зачем сервис, если нужно только показать уведомление - `BroadcastReceiver` проще и легче.

Comment: @woess тогда проблема другая. При нажатии на уведомлении не вызовется активити. Я хочу чтобы пользователь мог зайти в приложение при нажатии на кнопку, но AlarmManager сам этого не запускал.

Comment: Нужно `PendingIntent` на запуск `Activity` добавить к уведомлению -  в Вашем коде в вопросе это сделано, только лишь перенести этот код в `BroadcastReceiver`